# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus when the integrand is logarithmic derivative

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f(z)$ be an entire function and let $C$ be a broken line segment from $2$ to $2+2i$ to $1+2i$, and given that $f(z)$ is non zero on $C$.

Fundamental theorem of Calculus(FToC): If a continuous function $f$ has a primitive $F$ in $\Omega$, and $\gamma$ is a curve in $\Omega$ that begins at $w_{1}$ and ends at $w_{2}$, then $\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz = F(w_{2}) - F(w_{1})$

**Question:** How by the fundamental theorem of Calculus we have $$\Im\left(\int_{C} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz\right)=\Im\left(\log\left(f\left(1+2i\right)\right)\right)$$
where $\Im$ denotes the imaginary part and $f(z)$ is non zero on $C$.

Since $f(z)$ is entire and non zero on $C$ but then $f(z)$ might be $0$ in some domain containing curve $C$. Then how FToC applies here? Do we require parametrizing the segment?

**Edit** If we consider $f(z)=\left(z-(\frac{1}{4}+i)\right)\left(z-(\frac{3}{4}+i)\right)\left(z-(\frac{1}{4}-i)\right)\left(z-(\frac{3}{4}-i)\right)$.
Consider a rectangle $R=\{x+
iy\in\mathbb{C}\mid 0\leq x\leq 1, 0\leq y\leq 2\}$ and $\#Z$ be the no. of zeros of $f$ inside $R$. By Argument principle on $R$,   $$\#Z= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial R} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz=2\tag{1}$$
Since $f(z)=f(1-z)$ so $$\#Z= \frac{1}{\pi}\Im\left(\int_{L} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz\right)\tag{2}$$
where $L: 1\to 1+2i\to \frac
{1}{2}+2i$. By FToC, $(2)$ becomes $$\#Z= \frac{1}{\pi}\Im\left(\int_{L} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz\right)=\frac{1}{\pi}\Im\left(\log\left(f\left(\frac{1}{2}+2i\right)\right)\right)\tag{3}=0$$
Why $(1)$ and $(3)$ contradict each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is entire (i.e. also continuous) and $f(z) \neq 0$ on $C$, we can for each point $z'\in C$ find a small neighbourhood $U(z')$ so that $f(z) \neq 0$ $\forall z\in U(z')$. So basically we can find an open set $U := \bigcup\limits_{z'\in C} U(z')$, so that $C \subset U$ and $f(z)\neq 0$ for every $z\in U$.

This domain is simply connected, so each holomorphic function on $U$ has a primitive (theorem of Morera).  This includes $\frac{f'}{f}$, so it has a primitive and is thus subject to the fundamental theorem.

**Edit** Regarding your edit.
As long as the domain $D$ is simply connected, we have a primitive. Note that this is a topological obstruction, not something that comes from the function.

The basic problem is that the complex logarithm is not globally defined as a function because it has different branches: For each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, there is a possible complex logarithm $\operatorname{Log} : (0,\infty)\times [-\pi,\pi)\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, which maps $z = |z|\cdot e^{i\varphi}$ to $\log|z|+i\cdot(\varphi+n2\pi)$ (here $\log$ means the standard real logarithm function).

So whenever the argument of the complex number $f(z)$ inside of $\operatorname{Log}(f(z))$ leaves $(n\pi,(n+2)\pi)$, there occurs a "jump" with height $2\pi i$. That's why, for example, the integral of $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ does not vanish on $\partial B_1(0)$.

Maybe you already knew all of this, but that's basically where your "contradiction" comes from: While integrating along $\partial R$, the primitive of $f'/f$ changes twice by $2\pi i$.

You can calculate this explicitely by splitting $\partial R$ into separate curves and then use the fundamental theorem on each of those.

**Edit 2**
Maybe I should have just said that it is very important that we keep an eye on the argument of $f(z)$, as we integrate over the curve $\partial R$. Lets write $\partial R = L \cup L' \cup [0,1]$, where $L'$ is just your L-shaped curve $L$ reflected along the line $\Re (z) = 1/2$.

Let's say we parametrize $L$ via $L(t), t\in[0,1]$, then $$f(L(0)) = f(1) = 425/256, \text{ and}$$
$$f(L(1)) = f(1/2+2i) = 2465/256$$

Both values are real, however the argument of $f$ has already changed by $2\pi$ (as can be seen in the picture: This is the red part), which we can see by comparing $\Im(f(L(t))$ for values of $t$ close to $0$ (where it is positive) and close to $1$ (where it is negative).

This means that when calculating the integral, we get $$\Im\int\limits_L \frac{f'}{f}dz = \Im(\operatorname{Log}(f(1/2+2i))-\operatorname{Log}(f(1)) )= \Im(... + 2\pi i) = 2\pi$$

Now as you already mentioned, due to its symmetry $f(z) = f(1-z)$, we get that $$\Im \int\limits_{L'} ... = \Im\int\limits_L ... = 2\pi,$$ this is the blue part in the picture (i.e. $f(L')$).

Finally, on the last piece of the curve, the part from $0$ to $1$ along the real axis, the imaginary part of $f$ is constantly zero, so the argument doesn't change (see the little black part of the curve in the picture) and thus: $$\Im\int\limits_{[0,1]} ... = 0$$

I think the picture says more than everything I've written though: You can clearly see that while walking along $f(\partial R)$, the argument changes two times in the same direction by $2\pi$.
[[image: The curve <span class=]$f(\partial R)$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69hTS.jpg)

Comment: Thank you. Please tell me the reason for your statement "This domain is simply connected, so each holomorphic function on U has a primitive (theorem of Morera)"?

Comment: If we consider $f(z)=\left(z-(\frac{1}{4}+i)\right)\left(z-(\frac{3}{4}+i)\right)\left(z-(\frac{1}{4}-i)\right)\left(z-(\frac{3}{4}-i)\right)$.
Consider a rectangle $R=\{x+
iy\in\mathbb{C}\mid 0\leq x\leq 1, 0\leq y\leq 2\}$ and $\#Z$ be the no. of zeros of $f$ inside $R$. By Argument principle on $R$,   $$\#Z= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial R} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz=2\tag{1}$$

Comment: Since $f(z)=f(1-z)$ so $$\#Z= \frac{1}{\pi}\Im\left(\int_{L} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz\right)\tag{2}$$
where $L: 1\to 1+2i\to \frac
{1}{2}+2i$. By FToC, $(2)$ becomes $$\#Z= \frac{1}{\pi}\Im\left(\int_{L} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz\right)=\frac{1}{\pi}\Im\left(\log\left(f\left(\frac{1}{2}+2i\right)\right)\right)\tag{3}=0$$
Why $(1)$ and $(3)$ contradict each other?

Comment: I will accept your answer. Please answer my above last doubt.

Comment: First off, about the "This domain is simply connected, so each holomorphic function on U has a primitive (theorem of Morera)" part: A domain $U$ is called simply connected if each loop in $U$ can be contracted to a point. If you make a sketch of the domain constructed in my comment (you just take the given curve $C$ and then basically find a small (but open) tube around it), you will see that this is satisfied. Alternatively, you can modify $U$ a bit to make it starshaped with vantage point $2+2i$.

Comment: Secondly, about the second bit: The argument principle only works integrals over closed curves, so (1) is correct, so since $C$ is not closed, the integral $\frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_C\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz$ is not subject to the principle and thus (2) is not correct.

Comment: No. I am writing that the integral is Imaginary part of logarithmic derivative of the function over the path L. Because the rest of the parts are absorbed using the functional equation $f(z)=f(1-z)$ and $\overline {f(z)}=f(\overline{z})$ (Schwarz reflection principle)

Comment: But which curve are you integrating over in this calculation? If you use $\partial R$, you don't need Schwarz, since you're never below the real axis. It would help if you could write how exactly you've come to the conclusion that your formula (2) is correct.

Comment: I am integrating in equation (2) over the cruve L. Since $f(z)$ is symmetrical with respect to $\Re(z)=1/2$, so we get equation (2).

Comment: That's not what I mean. Here's to little space, I will write my answer as an edit in my original post.

Comment: Please edit your answer. I will happily accept it :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Which two curves should I split $\partial R$ to use the fundamental theorem on each of those. Note that my curve $L$ is a "L-shaped" curve. When we use $\log (z_1z_2z_3z_4)=\log z_1+\log z_2+\log z_3+\log z_4$ and then using FToC on each of 4 integrals I am getting the result. But what is the problem in my edit where I use FToC on L?

Comment: Your curve $L$ leads from $1$ to $1/2+2i$. Notice that when $z$ reaches $1/2+2i$, the argument of $f$ has already crossed $2\pi$: $f(0)$ is real, $f(1/2+2i)$ is real, and on one hand we can see that $\Im f(L(t\searrow 0)) >0$ and on the other $\Im f(L(t\nearrow 1))<0$. So $f(L(t))$ has done one full rotation and thus $\Im\operatorname{Log}(f(1/2+2i)) = \Im(2465/256 + i\cdot 2\pi) = 2\pi$. The same thing happens when integrating across the second $L$ due to the symmetry you already mentioned. On the missing bit from $0$ to $1$, we see that $f(z)$ is always real, so the argument doesn't change

Comment: So basically taking the imaginary part of the integral over the logarithmic derivative gives you the total change in the argument of your function between the start and the end of the curve.

Comment: Sorry I could not follow your second last comment that $f(L(t))$ has done one full rotation and $\Im Log (f(1/2+2i))=\Im(2465/256+2\pi i)$. How did you get that $f(L(t))$ has done one full rotation and how did you get $2465/256$ as real part?

Comment: Okay I'll do another edit, one second ^^

Comment: Please do the edit in your answer explaining your idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Why are you using capital log i.e. $\operatorname{Log}$ in your second edit? Is it to get a single valued logarithm?

Comment: Basically $\log$ means the unique real function $\log : (0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is inverse to $\exp : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow(0,\infty)$, while $$\operatorname{Log} : \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow  (0,\infty)+i[n\pi,(n+2)\pi),n\in\mathbb{Z}$$ is one branch of all possible complex logarithms. Because of the identity $$\operatorname{Log}(z) = \log |z| + i\cdot(\operatorname{arg}(z)+n2\pi),$$ it is helpfull to distinguish the two logarithms with different symbols.

Comment: I am accepting your answer. Thank you a lot.